# Number of other close votes don't match when for the off-topic detailed list

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

Just now, when reviewing close votes I voted to close a question and saw that there were four other votes cast for off-topic

[image]

but clicked off-topic I could only see one other vote, the other 3 was missing.

[image]

I have been seeing this issue many times today.

Comment: @hims056 You are right, that answered my question.